# ethereumjs - signature security issue

Tags: javascript, ethereum, digital-signature, web3js

Im new to smart contracts world. I have a doubt about the digital signature security.
I wanted to know if an attacker can reuse my same signed message and send it several times to another address?

client code example:

```
var msg = "hello";
var sh3 = web3.sha3(msg);

web3.eth.sign(account, sh3, (error, result) => {
     sendToServer({ sign: result, message: msg });
});
```

server side:

```
const sign = data.sign;
const message = Buffer.Buffer(data.msg);

const stringToSign = EthJS.sha3(message);

const res = EthJS.fromRpcSig(sign);

const pubKey  = EthJS.ecrecover(stringToSign, res.v, res.r, res.s);
const addrBuf = EthJS.pubToAddress(pubKey);
const addr    = EthJS.bufferToHex(addrBuf);

console.log(addr);
```

yes this code it is a valid proof that at least the first time a certain address sent the message. but an attacker can steal this message and can continue to resend it. At this point the server can not know if the message was sent from the original address or from another person. What is my fault?

Comment: I'm not a ethereum specialist, but in general messages themselves contain sequence numbers, time stamps and such to avoid *replay attacks*. There, I've at least given you the term to look for :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes is right. See my post [Signing and Verifying Messages in Ethereum](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/), particularly the section "Avoiding Replay Attacks."